# Referencing two tables

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to create a database in Visual Studio 2012. I have three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users] (
    [user_id]   INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [user_name] NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [user_pass] NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [name]      NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Surname]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [email]     NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([user_id] ASC),
    UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([email] ASC)
);
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Roles] (
    [user_id] INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Users(user_id),
    [role_id] INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([role_id] ASC, [user_id] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Apodosi_rolon] (
    [role_id] INT NOT NULL,
    [role_name] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([role_id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_ROLES_APODOSI+_ROLON]FOREIGN KEY ([role_id]) REFERENCES [Roles]([role_id])
);
```

But the Foreign Key in the `Apodosi_rolon` doesn't work. I saw how to create this constraint in this question: [How to reference two tables in Visual Studio 2012 by adding foreign key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16751000/how-to-reference-two-tables-in-visual-studio-2012-by-adding-foreign-key)

But I still get this error:

> SQL71516 :: The referenced table '[dbo].[Roles]' contains no primary or candidate keys that match the referencing column list in the foreign key. If the referenced column is a computed column, it should be persisted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data structure doesn't make sense to me.  I would expect to have a `Users` table, `Roles` table, and a `UserRoles` table.  These would have definitions like this:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
     user_id int not null primary key
);

CREATE TABLE Roles (
    role_id INT NOT NULL,
    [role_name] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([role_id] ASC)       
);

CREATE TABLE UserRoles (
    [user_id] INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Users(user_id),
    [role_id] INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Roles(role_id),
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([role_id] ASC, [user_id] ASC)
);
```

Obviously, the names of things could be different in different languages.  However, it doesn't make sense to have a table called `Roles` where the `Role_Id` is *not* the primary key.

Also, in such tables, often you want the primary keys to be identity columns so they are auto-incremented.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `users` table have primary key in `user_id` column.
see blow is working.

```
CREATE TABLE Users( 
        user_id  INT   IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL, 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (user_id ASC) 
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Roles] (
    [user_id] INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Users(user_id),
    [role_id] INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([role_id] ASC, [user_id] ASC)
);
```

If you remove primary key it is not working and got same error as you mansion.